# Is "Harshly" the opposite of "Gently"? Is it okay to say "Please don't type harshly on the keyboard" instead of "Please type gently on the Keyboard"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> [gent‧ly](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gently) /ˈdʒentli/ ●●○ W3 adverb     1 in a gentle way
>
> ‘You go back to bed now, ’ he said gently.
>
> She kissed me gently on the cheek.
>
> Gently cook the peppers for 10–15 minutes.
>
> Rain pattered gently on the roof above.
>
> The road curved gently upwards.

Is "**Harshly**" the opposite of "**Gently**"?

Is it okay to say "**Please don't type harshly on the keyboard**" instead of "**Please type gently on the Keyboard**"?

Comment: Probably say `violently` is the opposite of `gently`. Although with that specific use, I would probably say `Please don't type so hard on the keyboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Harshly"` is alright, but `"Please don't type harshly on the keyboard"` sounds a little unnatural. `"Harshly"` is an adverb referring to the manner of typing, so it should go at the end of the sentence. You could say `"Please don't type on the keyboard so harshly"` or `"Please don't type so harshly"` and that would sound more natural.

Another word you could use is `"roughly"`. It has the same meaning and sounds less formal - `"Please don't type on the keyboard so roughly."`

`"Violently"` would also work but `"typing violently"` sounds like they are typing much more roughly than just `"typing roughly"`.